# ID param not being sent to Controller when manually changing routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have looked through the other answers provided on StackOverflow, and none of them answered my question. Here is what is happening with my code.

**Error**

```
undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass
```

**Problem:**
It looks like the param id is not being sent to the controller from the form as they show up as nil in the console using byebug.

console readout:

```
(byebug) params[:id]
nil
(byebug) @support
nil
(byebug) params[:title]
nil
(byebug) params[:support]
<ActionController::Parameters {"title"=>"Test", "subtitle"=>"testing", 
"website"=>"www.test.com", "type_of_support"=>"", "description"=>""}
permitted: false>
(byebug) params[:support][:id]
nil
(byebug) params[:support][:title]
"Test"
```

I do not believe that the problem is with the form as it is the same form partial used for the new/create action and the params are sent to the controller then and the object is created (though in that case there is no id, since it is generated when creating the object, not passed from the form).

You can see in my code below that the route for `PATCH` is just 'support' without the `:id` param. If I try to add that to the route, I get an error stating that there is no route matching 'support/'. So, I have to take away the `:id` param in the route for it to pass the information to the controller.

I am at a loss here. How do I pass the `:id` to the controller? How does rails do this? Before I manually change the routes, the automatic routes from `resources :supports` includes an `:id` param for the `PATCH` route and it works. What am I doing wrong that it won't allow me to add that to the route?

**Code:**

config/routes.rb

```
get    'support',          as: 'supports',     to: 'supports#index'
post   'support',                              to: 'supports#create'
get    'support/new',      as: 'new_support',  to: 'supports#new'
get    'support/:id/edit', as: 'edit_support', to: 'supports#edit'
get    'support/:title',   as: 'support_page', to: 'supports#show'
patch  'support/',                             to: 'supports#update'
put    'support/:id',                          to: 'supports#update'
delete 'supports/:id',                         to: 'supports#destroy'
```

Results this for rake routes:

```
supports     GET    /support(.:format)                supports#index
support      POST   /support(.:format)                supports#create
new_support  GET    /support/new(.:format)            supports#new
edit_support GET    /support/:id/edit(.:format)       supports#edit
support_page GET    /support/:title(.:format)         supports#show
             PATCH  /support(.:format)                supports#update
             PUT    /support/:id(.:format)            supports#update
             DELETE /supports/:id(.:format)           supports#destroy
```

app/controllers/supports_controllers.rb

```
class SupportsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_support_by_title, only: [:show]
  before_action :set_support_by_id,    only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @supports = Support.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @support = Support.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @support = Support.new(support_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @support.save
        format.html { redirect_to @support, 
                      notice: 'Support was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    # byebug
    respond_to do |format|
      if @support.update(support_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @support, 
                      notice: 'Support was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @support.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to supports_url, 
                    notice: 'Support was successfully destroyed.' }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_support_by_title
      @support = Support.find_by(title: params[:title])
      # byebug
    end

    def set_support_by_id
      @support = Support.find(params[:id])
      # byebug
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, 
    # only allow the white list through.

    def support_params
      params.require(:support).permit(:title, 
                                      :subtitle, 
                                      :website, 
                                      :type_of_support, 
                                      :description)
    end
end
```

app/views/supports/edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Editing Support</h1>

<%= render 'form', support: @support %>

<%= link_to 'Show', support_page_path(@support.title) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', supports_path %>
```

app/views/supports/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: support, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if support.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(support.errors.count, "error") %> 
          prohibited this support from being saved:
      </h2>

      <ul>
      <% support.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    Title: 
    <%= form.text_field :title, id: :support_title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    Subtitle: 
    <%= form.text_field :subtitle, id: :support_subtitle %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    Website: 
    <%= form.text_field :website, id: :support_website %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    Type of Support: 
    <%= form.text_field :type_of_support, id: :support_type %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    Description: 
    <%= form.text_area :description, id: :support_description %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing this question, I thought of something and tried it. And it worked. Instead of re-writing all of the routes myself, I wrote only 2 and used the `resources :supports, except: [:index, :show]` to have rails generate the others. This solved my issue.

**Explanation**

I knew that something was going on behind the scenes that I did not understand. The entire process worked fine before I started to change the routes. So, something in there was incorrect. (I still don't know what it is and how to change it.)

The only two routes that I really want to be changed are the two that users see. I don't care about how the routes look in the admin backend. So, that meant that I only needed to change the routes for index and show to be SEO friendly and look better in the browser. So, to do that I wrote the routes like this:

config/routes.rb

```
resources :supports, except: [:index, :show]

get 'support', as: 'support_index', to: 'supports#index'
get 'support/:title', as: 'support_page', to: 'supports#show'
```

This then created all of the new, create, edit, update, destroy routes for me. After doing this, this is how my routes now look:

```
supports      POST   /supports(.:format)               supports#create
new_support   GET    /supports/new(.:format)           supports#new
edit_support  GET    /supports/:id/edit(.:format)      supports#edit
support       PATCH  /supports/:id(.:format)           supports#update
              PUT    /supports/:id(.:format)           supports#update
              DELETE /supports/:id(.:format)           supports#destroy
support_index GET    /support(.:format)                supports#index
support_page  GET    /support/:title(.:format)         supports#show
```

As you can see, the `PATCH` route is now getting the param `:id` to be able to update the record.

Now, I just had to change a few of the redirects in the controller after create, update and destroy like this:

```
def create
  @support = Support.new(support_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @support.save
      format.html { redirect_to support_page_path(title: @support.title), 
                    notice: 'Support was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @support.update(support_params)

      format.html { redirect_to support_page_path(title: @support.title), 
                    notice: 'Support was successfully updated.' }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
    end
  end
end

def destroy
  @support.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to support_index_path, 
                  notice: 'Support was successfully deleted.' }
  end
end
```

These `redirect_to` statements now match the routes that I generated for index and show.

And now everything works.

So, problem solved, though I still don't know what I was doing wrong before. Any light that can be shed would be appreciated.